# com.android.systemui has stopped

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-studio

Hi I am Using Sony Experia Neo V (MT11i) Phone with android version 4.0.4 to test my app from android studio Ver. 2.3 Canary

Some time it just automatically restarts my mobile when randomly after the Debug/ run . After starting up it give
com.android.systemui has stopped

and the top bar with the Mobile signal time , updates etc... disappears. no matter what i do the system can not be again make it normal. i rebooted several times , formatted , reset to factory settings etc.. nothing seems to be working .

then during one of the random manual restart it goes back normal as if nothing happens. ( strangely changes the background some times) .

Any one has any clue how to stop this from happening , it is really frustrating all the time

Comment: Does the phone have a stock ROM installed, or have you rooted/installed something else?

Comment: No just the stock ROM not yet rooted,  just after factory reset , I have been working on some app development in Android studio that's it, just developer option and is enabled  ( USB debugging) and auto sleep mode is deactivated nothing else

Comment: Hi there any solutions???  I have tried most  option from google search

Comment: Have you see this thread?  Maybe something there can help.  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39832/xperia-neo-v-not-able-to-load-os

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you actually are installing you developed app on your phone.
Just uninstall it and see what's happening...  It is most probable cause of you phone misbehaving....
If an application doesn't start properly a number of times android stops trying to use it...
One possible scenario would be that you have marked your app (intentionally or not) as a launcher and it keeps crashing.